# Is there a way to see what a executed BATCH file did?

Tags: windows, batch-file, windows-server-2003

I'm pretty sure the answer to my question is a simple "No", but I'm going to try it anyways. (And a plain No would help me also.)

We've got a shared computer. Folks may use it as they do, but they won't do more than Googling or sending mails.

Today someone executed a batch file, took his USB stick off and went away.

There is no damage done. I'm just curious if there is a way to see what has been in this batch file. If this is plain source code or just "it MAY have done these things" doesn't matter.

Maybe Windows keeps some tracking? But I never saw this. The user account is a domain account from a Windows Server 2003. Maybe this one keeps tracking?

**Is there a way to find out what batch files recently have executed?**

```
Windows 7
Intel-based
User account is accessed over domain
Hasn't been shut down since then
```

Comment: Did you mean that you want to track this batch or may be where it is executed i mean its path ?? because in taskmanager you found only cmd.exe executed not its path ? is this what you want ??

Comment: just can see history of usb port from registry key "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum\USBSTOR" but no more for tracking you should before that use firewall like kaspersky and try to use utility usb for tracking all usb in domain

Comment: No, I want to find out what this batch file did. I have no idea. :) || Well okay... so this seems to lead to a No. :C

Comment: Hmmmm.. i guess that you want to code a file stealer when an USB key is plugged so it copy all batch from there ,isn't true ?  :)

Comment: Windows creates a prefetch file for all applications started in %windir%\prefetch which you could look on to find out if applications were started on this computer usually not started. Check also the file time of each prefetch file. Windows records also every started application in registry under `HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\ShellNoRoam\MUICache`. And you can look in event logs of Windows if there is something suspect in critical time period. But a full log of all commands executed by batch file does not exist without having extra software installed which creates such logs.

Comment: I think this is really a question for SuperUser.SE. There is no real code that can be put into answers here, and I think you've got a better chance with the experts on [SuperUser](http://superuser.com/)